# A regular $2017$-gon is partitioned into triangles by a set of non-intersecting diagonals. Prove that only one is a acute angled.

Tags: geometry

A regular $2017$-gon is partitioned into triangles by a set of non-intersecting diagonals.  Prove that among those triangles only one is a acute angled.

Comment: Draw a picture and prove it with a pentagon first.

Answer (score 5):

Since $2017$ is odd there is no diagonal going through the centre of the circle. Therefore there is exactly one triangle containing $M$ in its interior. This triangle is acute, all others are obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

A triangle will have $k$ vertices to one side and $n-3-k$ to the other, for $0\le k\le n-3$. The [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) says that the angles of this triangle are
$$
\left\{\frac\pi{n}\,,\,(k+1)\frac\pi{n}\,,\,(n-2-k)\frac\pi{n}\right\}
$$

[image]

This means that every such triangulation of a regular $n$-gon will have an identical set if triangles, just oriented and positioned differently. Each triangle is labeled with its $k$ value:

[image]

If $n$ is odd, only when $k=\frac{n-3}2$ will the triangle be acute, with angles
$$
\left\{\frac\pi{n}\,,\,\frac{n-1}2\frac\pi{n}\,,\,\frac{n-1}2\frac\pi{n}\right\}
$$
If $n$ is even, when $k=\frac{n-2}2$ or $k=\frac{n-4}2$, the triangle will be right, with angles
$$
\left\{\frac\pi{n}\,,\,\frac{n-2}2\frac\pi{n}\,,\,\frac\pi2\right\}
$$
and there will be no acute triangles.